# Выводить элементы на одной карте

Tags: javascript, jquery, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

В данном примере все работает хорошо, но строится новая карта.
Нужно чтобы пункты выводились на одной карте, а не создавалась новая.
[Вот пример кода](https://jsfiddle.net/zw5Lsjtq/4/) (работает быстрее чем здесь)

Если выношу создание карты за пределы ajax, то карта не создается вовсе.
[Как-то так](https://jsfiddle.net/zw5Lsjtq/5/)
Может это потому что строится карта динамически и нужно обрабатывать через [on(change)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752321/jquery-live-vs-on-method-for-adding-a-click-event-after-loading-dynamic-ht), но и так не выходит

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#cdek_point_id').change(function() {
   var pointCode = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'https://integration.cdek.ru/pvzlist.php',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        data : { cityid : 320},
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(result) {
          console.log('LAM', result);
          var points = result.getElementsByTagName("Pvz");
          // в result находится сам xml
          console.log(result);
          // в points находится объект со списками пунктов 
          console.log(points);
          
          // Тут получаем координату выбранного элемента
          var point = result.querySelector('[Code=' + pointCode + ']');
          var lat = parseFloat(point.getAttribute('coordY'));
          var lon = parseFloat(point.getAttribute('coordX'));
          var centerPoint = [lat, lon];
          
          ymaps.ready(init);

          function init() {

            var myMap = new ymaps.Map("YMapsID", {
                // Нужно здесь указать координаты выбранного пункта.
                  // например, как-то сравнить pointCode с полученным результатом и вывести только 
                  // координаты из массива где Code == pointCode
                  center: centerPoint, 
                  zoom: 16
              }, {
                  searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
              });


            for (i=0;i<points.length;i+=1) {
       // Здесь я уже перебираю пункты и вывожу на карту
              var address = result.getElementsByTagName("Pvz")[i].getAttribute('FullAddress');
              var phone = result.getElementsByTagName("Pvz")[i].getAttribute('Phone');
              var workTime = result.getElementsByTagName("Pvz")[i].getAttribute('WorkTime');
              var info = address + '<br><b>Тел.:</b> ' + phone + '<br><b>Время.:</b> ' + workTime;

              var site = result.getElementsByTagName("Pvz")[i].getAttribute('Site');

              var lat = parseFloat(result.getElementsByTagName("Pvz")[i].getAttribute('coordY'));
              var lon = parseFloat(result.getElementsByTagName("Pvz")[i].getAttribute('coordX'));

              // Создаем геообъект с типом геометрии "Точка".
              var myGeoObject = new ymaps.GeoObject({
                // Описание геометрии.
                geometry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: [lat, lon]
                },
                // Свойства.
                properties: {
                    balloonContent: info,
                    hintContent: info
                }
              }, {
                // Опции.
                preset: 'islands#blueIcon'
              });

              myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
});
```

```css
html, body, #YMapsID {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
#YMapsID {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<select id="cdek_point_id" >
  <option value="0">- выберите пункт -</option>
  <option value="LPC1">Россия, Липецкая обл., Липецк, пл. Петра Великого, 5, 05</option>
  <option value="LPC2">Россия, Липецкая обл., Липецк, пр-т Победы, 128</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<div id="YMapsID"></div>
```

Comment: Проблема-то в чем? Вынесите создание карты из `ajax()`

Comment: Если выношу создание карты за пределы ajax, то карта не создается вовсе. https://jsfiddle.net/zw5Lsjtq/5/

Comment: я обновил немного вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Выделю скелет из вашего кода:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#cdek_point_id').change(function() {
    // ..
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function(result) {
          ymaps.ready(init);    
          function init() {
            var myMap = new ymaps.Map("YMapsID", {
            // ...
              myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);
              // ...
```

Теперь как сделать чтобы работало:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  ymaps.ready(init);
  function init() {
    // создаем карту одну на 
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("YMapsID", {
    // ...
    // цепляем обработчик на select
    $('#cdek_point_id').change(function() {
      // ..
      $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function(result) {
          // ...
            myMap.geoObjects.add(myGeoObject);
            // ...
```

Вообще неплохо еще бы сделать "кеширование" адресов или создать объекты заранее, а потом показывать на карте нужный и скрывать ненужные, не обращаясь постоянно за координатами.

**Обновлено** Более пристально посмотрел на ваш код и понял что вам вообще не нужно делать AJAX-запрос при каждом изменении селекта. Вы ведь каждый раз возвращаете сразу весь список и потом берете нужный элемент. Поэтому нужно вначале вместе с инициализацией карты (или до) запросить список, а потом уже показывать нужные точки при переключении.

Comment: у меня там данные для центра карты из аякс запроса берутся

Comment: @dmitriy [`myMap.setCenter(...)`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#setCenter)

Comment: `$(document).ready` можно убрать, `ymaps.ready` уже ждет `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: @flapenguin только в документации этого нет. Вы это в коде Яндекс.Карты видели?

Comment: Есть.
"Выполняет переданную функцию, когда API и DOM готовы к использованию."
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ready-docpage/

Comment: @vsesh Точно. Где раньше были мои глаза :)

Comment: Нашел где были. Наткнулся на прошлую версию доков https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/ref/reference/ready-docpage/